# Job submission fails with generic 503 error when max-jobs-per-context value exceeds

Tags: apache-spark, jersey, spark-jobserver

I have set context-per-jvm = true and max-jobs-per-context = 4 in my config file.

I have pre-created context using following curl command:
`curl -d ""  'http://jobserver:8090/contexts/test-context'`

I am using following curl command to submit a job: 
`curl -d "" 'http://jobserver:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=com.xyz.Test&context=test-context'`

After submitting 4 jobs using above command, submission of 5th job gives following response:

```
{
  "status": "NO SLOTS AVAILABLE",
  "result": "Too many running jobs (4) for job context 'test-context'"
}
```

Which is a decent and useful response.

However, when I am submitting the job from my Java program using [Jersey API](https://jersey.java.net/), job submission of 5th job fails with a generic 503 exception without any specific error message.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebTarget resource = client.target("http://jobserver:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=com.xyz.Test&context=test-context");
        Response response = resource.request().post(Entity.json(""), Response.class);
        System.out.println("Response:" + response);
    }
```

Output:

`Response:InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://jobserver:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=com.xyz.Test&context=test-context, status=503, reason=Service Unavailable}}`

What is the reason behing this inconsistancy? Am I missing something in my Jersey API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the specific JSON response using the following method:

`response.readEntity(JSONObject.class)` or `response.readEntity(String.class)`